# Getting "Error retrieving blocks, missed (#) transactions for block with hash" while running pruned node

Tags: monerod, pruning, server

I've been running a pruned node on a very low-end server ( <2GB of RAM), and monerod keeps spitting out lines like that every couple blocks.

May be relevant, opening a wallet with the RPC throws this warning: `WARNING: You may not have a high enough lockable memory limit, see ulimit -l` as well.

Comment: As pruning is so new, probably more sensible to open a ticket at https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues. Theres been a couple of little teething problems.

Answer (score 2):

From [moneromoo on Github](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/5654#issuecomment-502471067):

> That's from nodes that don't understand pruning are asking you for data that you pruned. It's OK.
>
> For the lockable memory issue, you can increase the amount of lockable memory using the command the message is giving you.